# Visual team Service The field 'Assigned To' contains the value '' that is not in the list of supported values

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a Team Service account which I linked to my AD. When I assign a task to a user everything is working well but when I try to assign a task to a group that I create, I am getting the error :

> The field 'Assigned To' contains the value '[Myproject]\MyTeam
>   ' that is not in the list of
>   supported values

I try search on google but could not find any resource that helps me to solve the problem.

What is the problem and What is the solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

By default on-premise TFS doesn't allow you a assign to a Group / Team, but with customisations to the Work Item template, you can enable it.

The existing VSTS customisation functionality doesn't appear to allow you to add groups into there.

I've looked on [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services?query=assignedto) and I cannot see a request for it.